# Why should I add a constraint to a Haskell function even if I have implemented the necessary instances for all possible DataKinds?

Tags: haskell, constraints, data-kinds

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data RegStatus = Registered | Anonim

newtype UserId (r :: RegStatus) = UserId Int

class GetRegStatus (r :: RegStatus)  where
  getRegStatus :: UserId r -> RegStatus

instance GetRegStatus 'Registered where
  getRegStatus _ = Registered

instance GetRegStatus 'Anonim where
  getRegStatus _ = Anonim

getStatus :: forall (r :: RegStatus).  UserId r -> RegStatus
getStatus = getRegStatus
```

Error: No instance for (GetRegStatus r) arising from a use of `getRegStatus'

But I already implemented GetRegStatus for all possible RegStatus data kinds.

Well, if I add a constraint, it works well.

```
getStatus :: forall r. GetRegStatus r =>  UserId r -> RegStatus
getStatus = getRegStatus
```

Is there any way to prove to the compiler that the GetRegStatus constraint is not needed?

Comment: Basically, _no it's not possible because type erasure_. It would require replacing `∀ (r :: RegStatus) . ` with `Π (r :: RegStatus) . `, using the fabled [Pi operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%CE%A0_type) which Haskell doesn't have. I've heard rumours that it might at some point be added. -- For now, you should probably use [singletons-th](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-th) to avoid having to write boilerplate for cases like this.

Comment: IIRC, type constraints also do something extra besides constraining types: they look for the "bag" of functions the typeclass defined, and pass the specific bag of that instance as parameter. So a typeclass here basically means the compiler makes a "hidden" type for `GetRegStatus` with one item the `getRegStatus`, and depending on the exact instance, it injects in this case the value for one of the two instances as hidden parameter to work with that.

Comment: To call `getRegStatus` GHC needs to be able to find an instance for `GetRegStatus r`, inside the implementation of `getStatus` where the type `r` is not known. You are thinking of this as merely a box-ticking exercise that shouldn't be required, because every possible `r` has an instance. But GHC doesn't merely need to know that an instance exists; it needs to know **which** instance to use; they have different implementations of `getRegStatus`. There isn't enough information to decide that inside `getStatus`; it needs to be passed in by the caller. That's exactly what a constraint is.